# IntelliJ: How can I always show parameter hints?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, parameters, hints

I'd like to always be able to see method parameter hints when filling in a method.

IntelliJ shows these hints, but they disappear after typing for a bit:

[image]

How can I make it so these popup hints always appear while typing out the method params?

Comment: See this [image with the relevant settings](https://i.imgur.com/BqL4Pop.png).

Comment: Or you can use Ctrl+P ( View-> Parameter Info)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable all the options in: `Editor` -> `General` -> `Code Completion` under the section `Parameter Info`:

[image]